# How do you do the vlog style cuts? Im new and dont know the name of the effect.

Tags: after-effects, premiere

So, im new to video editing, im about to start vlogging. I notice on vlogs theres an effect, its like some one talking, sitting in a chair, seems like when they switch points when theyre talking, seems like a new clip comes on, even tho its them in the same spot? Does that make sense? My friend told me it was called cuts, but ive been searching and that brings me back nothing.

Comment: You need to give us an example, it's impossible to tell what you mean.

Comment: Does this make sense....No, not really, do you have an example? there are many many many....sooo many YouTube videos and websites on "How to Vlog / Blog" I would suggest starting with some of these and learning from them to build your own style. as for effects, etc there are again many YouTube videos, plugins, both simple and advanced. without knowing exactly what you are looking for it is such a broad question.

Answer (score 3):

**Straight cut** is a change of shot without transition effect. **Jump cut** is a straight cut between two very similar shots, which would be perceived as a single shot if not for a slight change in position or lightning.

Professionals used to consider jump cuts a sign of an amateur, unacceptable for movies and broadcast TV. In the 1960s the French New Wave directors broke a lot of movie rules, including the "no jump cuts" rule. Nowadays you can see them in most vlogs, although the professionals still try to avoid them by using **cutaway**, which usually is sourced from **B-roll**.

Comment: My impression of such cuts common in vlogs is that they don't show amateur videography as much as they show amateur performance. I wonder why these vloggers can't seem to deliver their lines more than 8 seconds at a time. I personally can't stand this particular habit, which is why I watch almost no vlogs.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia Would you rather prefer a morph cut like this: https://metro.co.uk/2018/12/13/viewers-baffled-child-appears-teleport-tv-interview-8244024/ ;-) At least a jump cut clearly implies that something was cut out, while morph cuts or even traditional cutaways do not telegraph this message. But I agree, style-wise jump cuts are a pain to see, especially if they are frequent.

Comment: Well, yes, I prefer it, but if you are a news outlet, you better be careful about the impression you give. If a cut is not obvious, it can give the impression that two sentences were said in succession. In text, such a quote would never be acceptable without the ellipses (`...`) between them.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to what Rusty Core has already said in their excellent answer...

With vloggers there's a good chance that it's not a different clip that 'comes on'; it's the same take but the vlogger/editor has chopped out some content, which results in the jump cut (usually it's a pause or they've said something wrong or they just want to remove something that they have said). This is easier than constantly stopping and starting the recording every time you pause or make a mistake - you carry on shooting and then just trim down the take in the edit.

Of course, that's not a hard and fast rule and you will see times when there are more than one take - especially if the vlogger is making an addendum/amendment to something that they previously said.

The most important thing to remember with vlogging is that it's a very open and free-spirited form of content creation. There are almost no rules and doing things your way is one of the defining traits of vlogging.

You can find a load of great resources online to help you get started in editing, just search for 'Editing for beginners' on the search engine of your choice and you should find something - or just keep asking on here! Good luck!

Comment: "The most important thing to remember with vlogging is that it's a very open and free-spirited form of content creation. There are almost no rules and doing things your way is one of the defining traits of vlogging." Translation: it's okay to do like an amateur. Great point, however. Different art forms have different standards.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia Have you watched Casey Neistat's vlogs? They are jumpy, the camera often goes out of focus, yet they are very stylish in their own way to the point that many vloggers try to emulate his style. This is a testament to something people recognize and like.